# Why do the leaves on my black fig tree have white patches?

Tags: fruit-trees, figs

I bought a fig tree from a local DIY store. It has started developing these white patches. Does anybody know what they indicate?

[image]

Comment: Hi! How's this plant doing? Were you able to solve the problem? If not, can you post more pictures? Close-ups of the diseased parts, as well as the whole plant, would be great. If you have a solution, would you write it up as an answer here? That would be a big help for future visitors with a similar question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to me as a [sunburnt](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=plant+sunburnt&qpvt=plant+sunburnt&qpvt=plant+sunburnt&qpvt=plant+sunburnt&FORM=IQFRML). In the store, the plant was sheltered from direct sun. Then you put it outside, and that's too much sun for the leaves it had grown in the shades back there.

Its not too bad for it I think, and new leaves won't develop such weakness since they will grow in the sun. Maybe just remove it from full-day sunlight and leave it a week or so to adapt.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like powdery mildew.  And if it starts spreading it will move to all your plants.  If that's what it is it's very hard to treat but there are seats you can get that will get rid of it.  If I was you I would keep an eye on it and do a little research on powdery mildew.

Comment: That's not powdery mildew - the patches are paled and dried out. Clearly sunburn. And what do you mean by "seats [...] that will get rid of it"?